# Using Firebug to know where to get information with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, web-scraping, firebug

I'm currently trying to learn how to scrape diffrent site, so I got a couple on a list that I'm need to do. I'm not really sure how it works yet, but was wondering if I could use Firebug to find the specific part where I want my scraper to go to?

[test-page](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1701938)

The link is to one of the pages I'm trying to scrape from. From this one am I going to get the abstract section.

If I then go in firebug and find the classes I'm looking for I se that I can get the path in X-path. Is this something I can use to setup my scraper or?

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1] <-- Xpath to
```

And If I can use this to send my scraper there, how can some example look?
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: where is the affiliation?